# List specific directory and show image

Tags: php, html, directory

I have 2 php files that I am trying to combine:
The first.php file lists the contents of specific directory.
The second.php file is able to show the images of a specific directory.

What I try to do:
I want to list a directory "camera/images". On click on the link, the images of this directory should display.

Below code lists the directory "camera/images" and results like this.
- album1
- album2
- album3

Every album contains images, I would like to link from "first.php" and display the contained images.

first.php

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('camera/images'); 
echo '<ul>'; 
while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
{ 
if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
{ 
echo '<li><a href="camera/images/'.$read.'">'.$read.'</a></li>'; 
} 
} 
echo '</ul>'; 
closedir($dir); 
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
$files = glob("camera/images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$num = $files[$i];
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" />'."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> What I try to do: I want to list a directory "camera/images". On click
>   on the link, the images of this directory should display.

If you want something like this to occur without having to refresh the page you are going to need to use javascript.  And if you want the image to be retrieved at the time it is clicked then you will need to use an ajax call.

The simple answer overview:
I personally use the jquery library.  If you are familiar with javascript already then you can do it in normal javascript but I recommend jquery for its cross compatibility and general awesomeness.

You need to generate the page the way you want it to be shown as if everything had been clicked.  Then you need to make sure the div around the images is hidden.  Then you need to bind a click event to each link and unhide the div it is associated with.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) is an example that can help you.

I hope this points you in the right direction.